# Почему событие срабатывает только на первый элемент?

Tags: javascript

Здрасти, хочу сделать появление списка по клику по button, но скрипт работает только на первую button. Плчему? спс

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
document.querySelectorAll('.second-menu-btn').forEach(function (Btn) {
    Btn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        const path = event.currentTarget.dataset.path

        document.querySelectorAll('.wrap2').forEach(function (
            Content) {
            Content.classList.remove(
                'is-active')
        })
        document.querySelector('.wrap2').classList
            .add('is-active')
    })
})
```

});

```
<li class="section__top-nav-second-menu-item" id="list-initial-1">
                        <button class="second-menu-btn">
                            Реализм
                            <svg class="arrow-for-second-menu-btn" width="12" height="7" viewBox="0 0 12 7"
                                fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="M11 1L6 6L1 1" stroke="white" />
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                        <div class="wrap2" id="list-items">
                            <ul class="dop-list-items" data-simplebar>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Тинторетто</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-2">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Фридрих</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Леонардо</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-4">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Верроккьо</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Тинторетто</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-2">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Фридрих</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Леонардо</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-4">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Верроккьо</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
```

.wrap2 скрыт dispal none. нажимая на second-menu-btn у класса wrap2 display none меняется на display block

Comment: Есть предположение, что проблема не в кнопке, а в строчках с использованием `.wrap2`. Но чтобы точно ответить - нужна полная html разметка для анализа. **Плюс описание** что должен делать скрипт

Comment: В примере у вас и так один элемент с классом нужным, можно конкретней что хотите получить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас есть несколько списков, каждый из которых открывается при клике по кнопке, то, судя по вашей разметке, нужно делать видимым, первого "соседа" этой кнопки. Т.е. как-то так:

```js
  let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.second-menu-btn');
let lists = document.querySelectorAll('.wrap2');

for (let btn of btns) {
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
let delegateTarget = e.target.nextElementSibling
delegateTarget.classList.add('active');

for (let list of lists){
if(list!==delegateTarget){
list.classList.remove('active')
}
}


})
}
```

```css
.wrap2{
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<li class="section__top-nav-second-menu-item" id="list-initial-1">
                        <button class="second-menu-btn">
                            Реализм
                            <svg class="arrow-for-second-menu-btn" width="12" height="7" viewBox="0 0 12 7"
                                fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="M11 1L6 6L1 1" stroke="white" />
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                        <div class="wrap2" id="list-items">
                            <ul class="dop-list-items" data-simplebar>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Тинторетто</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-2">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Фридрих</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Леонардо</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-4">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Верроккьо</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Тинторетто</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-2">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Фридрих</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Леонардо</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-4">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Верроккьо</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="section__top-nav-second-menu-item" id="list-initial-1">
                        <button class="second-menu-btn">
                            Реализм
                            <svg class="arrow-for-second-menu-btn" width="12" height="7" viewBox="0 0 12 7"
                                fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="M11 1L6 6L1 1" stroke="white" />
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                        <div class="wrap2" id="list-items">
                            <ul class="dop-list-items" data-simplebar>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Тинторетто</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-2">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Фридрих</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Леонардо</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-4">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Верроккьо</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Тинторетто</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-2">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Фридрих</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Леонардо</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dop-list-item list-img-4">
                                    <a href="#" class="dop-list-item-link">Верроккьо</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
```

Comment: Если первый открыт, то при клике на второй, первый должен скрываться.

Comment: Ага, т.е. вы хотите сделать аккордеон. Так и бы сказали. Смотрите апдейт.

Comment: В точку, кайф. Спс